# Using Pandas, how to fix formatting of .sum().sum() using float_format

Tags: python, pandas, sum, format

I have the following csv read as a dataframe:

```
>>> test=pd.read_csv('C:/Temp/test.csv')
>>> test
     a    b    c
0  1.1  2.2  3.3
1  3.0  4.0  5.0
```

I want to add up all these numbers, displayed as currency.  I think the most efficient way to do this is to use a `.sum().sum()` method.

```
>>> pd.set_option('display.float_format','${:,.2f}'.format)
>>> test
      a     b     c
0 $1.10 $2.20 $3.30
1 $3.00 $4.00 $5.00
>>> test.sum()
a   $4.10
b   $6.20
c   $8.30
dtype: float64
>>> test.sum().sum()
18.6
```

The formatting option I want is working for the dataframe and the first sum; but the sum of the sum doesn't use the formatting, even though the datatype is still float:

```
>>> test.sum().sum().dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> test.sum().dtype
dtype('float64')
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: `test.sum().sum()` is a scalar， not in a DataFrame or Series, so `pd.set_option('display.float_format','${:,.2f}'.format)` does not affect it.

Comment: `test.sum().sum()` returns a single float number and no longer affected by `pd.set_option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `test.sum().sum()` is a scalar so it does not apply the pandas formatting options. To format this type of data you can use the standard python `format` function:

```
"${:,.2f}".format(df.sum().sum())
```